# Can I limit user access using OmniAuth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I want to use OmniAuth to allow users to sign on because I want to get their facebook profile pictures.  But I think Omniauth will allow anyone with a facebook account to signup and use the site.  Is there a way for me to only allow a select group of users to signup for and sign into the site?

Thanks.

Comment: What would you like to filter them by?  Facebook username?  Email address?  It is "possible" but it has to be a piece of information available to you in the auth hash.

Comment: I would like to filter by email address or to allow only friends of the Admin user.  I am not using Devise and currently have an authentication model set up from scratch.

Comment: Filtering by email and limiting registrations to people which are in your friend list is kind of tricky (facebook privilege settings), I think using registration tokens which are sent through invites are the way to go here, also as a side functionality you might add that a registering user needs to be cleared.